# Licence Key Android

Tags: android, google-play

I must publish my Android Application on the Google Play Store, but I have one question.

When I created a new account as developer, after the insert all the information relative my application, I received the "licence key base64 ", what is this licence?
What I must do with this licence? Is it suggested use it ?

Can someone tell me how implement it ?

I have also read all the google developer documentation but I dont understand how I can implement this licence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything you need can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html)

And the purpose of licensing is [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Short summary: unless you have paid app or in-app billing, you don't need it

Comment: Currently, the LVL library is also useful for free apps to avoid the use of a pirated copy, through the use of the APK expansion file as indicated in the documentation